# How can i remove NSInvalidArgumentException Trace: <redacted> <redacted> .. My App Name.. <redacted>.. from Google Analytics?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, crash-reports

Smart Peoples!!

I turned on the uncaught exception logging in my iOS app:

```
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 120;

[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-########-#"];

[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker = tracker;

[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
```

In Google Analytics, I can click Crashes and Exceptions under Behavior and see a couple of crash reports, but they look like this:

**ALL»EXCEPTION DESCRIPTION: NSInvalidArgumentException Trace: < redacted > < redacted > _CF_forwarding_prep_0 < redacted > 0x0005f4d3 My App Name < redacted > < redacted > < redacted > < redacted >**

What's with all the "redacted"? How do I get to see the actual exception message and stack trace? As is, this message is not very useful.

Also my client have'nt reported me about any kind of crashes So How can I remove this Exception from Google Analytics ?  Any Help Would be Highly Appreciable.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: looking forward on this solution too, but i guess its a google issue

Answer (score 0):

I had same question like you before and then somewhere in Google Groups I saw this- As per Google Analytics documentation/contract(I'll paste that link when I find it), they will not collect/show any user specific data. They will just give you stats on how many crashers happened and what kind of crasher was reported like NSInvalidArgumentException etc. 
You are not missing any config settings. Max you can do is add a secondary dimension to see which screen was affected. To get complete stack trace we integrated crashlytics (it is free from Twitter).